# Postgres composite type not using index

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, composite-types, postgresql-performance

I have a composite type where one subcolumn is an integer and the other is a numrange.

I'm using: `PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-5ubuntu1) 6.3.0 20170124, 64-bit`

And for the purposes of this testing `SET enable_seqscan=false`.

This uses the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM shot 
WHERE lower(shot.matchsecond) <@ (0, numrange(5, 10))::matchsecond_type;

Bitmap Heap Scan on shot  (cost=471.17..790.19 rows=50 width=45) (actual time=2.601..29.555 rows=5 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((matchsecond).match_id)::integer = (0)::integer)
  Filter: ((numrange(lower(((matchsecond).second)::numrange), lower(((matchsecond).second)::numrange), '[]'::text))::numrange <@ ('[5,10)'::numrange)::numrange)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9996
  Heap Blocks: exact=94
  Buffers: shared hit=193
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_shot_matchsecond  (cost=0.00..471.16 rows=10001 width=0) (actual time=2.516..2.516 rows=10001 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((matchsecond).match_id)::integer = (0)::integer)
        Buffers: shared hit=99
Planning time: 0.401 ms
Execution time: 29.623 ms
```

But this doesn't:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM shot 
WHERE lower(shot.matchsecond) <@ ((shot.matchsecond).match_id, numrange(5, 10))::matchsecond_type;

Seq Scan on shot  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000319.02 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.091..20.003 rows=5 loops=1)
  Filter: ((((matchsecond).match_id)::integer = ((matchsecond).match_id)::integer) AND ((numrange(lower(((matchsecond).second)::numrange), lower(((matchsecond).second)::numrange), '[]'::text))::numrange <@ ('[5,10)'::numrange)::numrange))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9996
  Buffers: shared hit=94
Planning time: 0.351 ms
Execution time: 20.075 ms
```

Note the `0` in the first compared to `(shot.matchsecond).match_id` in the second on the right hand side of the `<@`.  Interestingly, if the left hand side is simply `shot.matchsecond` instead of `lower(shot.matchsecond)`, the query manages to use the index.  The index is also used when constructing the numrange with functions like `numrange(lower((shot.matchsecond).second), lower((shot.matchsecond).second + 10))`.

Here are the relevant definitions:

```
CREATE DOMAIN matchsecond_match AS integer NOT NULL;
CREATE DOMAIN matchsecond_second AS numrange NOT NULL CHECK(VALUE <> numrange(0,0));

CREATE TYPE matchsecond_type AS (
    match_id matchsecond_match,
    second matchsecond_second
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matchsecond_contains_range(matchsecond_type, matchsecond_type)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$ SELECT $1.match_id = $2.match_id AND $1.second @> $2.second $$
LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OPERATOR @> (
    LEFTARG = matchsecond_type,
    RIGHTARG = matchsecond_type,
    PROCEDURE = matchsecond_contains_range,
    COMMUTATOR = <@,
    RESTRICT = eqsel,
    JOIN = eqjoinsel    
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matchsecond_contained_by_range(matchsecond_type, matchsecond_type)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$ SELECT $1.match_id = $2.match_id AND $1.second <@ $2.second $$
LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OPERATOR <@ (
    LEFTARG = matchsecond_type,
    RIGHTARG = matchsecond_type,
    PROCEDURE = matchsecond_contained_by_range,
    COMMUTATOR = @>,
    RESTRICT = eqsel,
    JOIN = eqjoinsel    
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower(matchsecond_type)
RETURNS matchsecond_type AS
$$ SELECT ($1.match_id, numrange(lower($1.second), lower($1.second), '[]'))::matchsecond_type $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And a test table:

Reminder: Use `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`

```
CREATE TABLE shot AS(
    SELECT i AS id, (0, numrange(i, i+1))::matchsecond_type AS matchsecond
    FROM generate_series(0,10000) AS i
);

ALTER TABLE shot ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
CREATE INDEX ix_shot_matchsecond
    ON shot
    USING gist (((matchsecond).match_id), ((matchsecond).second));
```

I tried adding this index, but it didn't change anything

```
CREATE INDEX ix_shot_lower_matchsecond
    ON shot (lower(matchsecond));
```

Comment: As you have no index usable on `lower(shot.matchsecond)`, it is no wonder no index is being used in that case.  Also, using the index as it is results in a plan that happens to be executed faster than the one with the bitmap index scan, so it's not a big win so far.

Comment: What do you mean by I have no index usable on it?  The first example uses `lower(shot.matchsecond)` and uses an index.  As for the speed, this query is just a way of testing whether the index is being used.